# Airberlin Platinum Service hotline

Tags: loyalty-programs, oneworld

Do anyone know what's the new hotline number for Airberlin's Topbonus platinum service hotline?

From https://topbonus.airberlin.com/web/tb/platinum-service, it says:

```
+49 (0)30 - 3434 3434
```

When I called the above number, it says that the number changed and from skype, I've called: 0180 6334 334

But I can't seem to call through.

Comment: Found the number by looking through my email `+49 30 221 511 51`... They really need to update their website.

Comment: Can you turn that into an answer so that others with the same problem could benefit from this ?

Comment: The thing is that "0180" number you tried to call falls into the German medium-cost "premium" number segment. Just like 0800 numbers in the US, they cannot be called from abroad, and they are typically not available when using services such as Skype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching through my previous email contact with the service hotline, the numbers are:

```
topbonus Platinum Hotline DE: +49 30 221 511 51 / Fax +49 30 221 511 52
topbonus Platinum Hotline AT: +43 1 928 00 99/ Fax +43 1 928 00 98
topbonus Platinum Hotline CH: +41 44 583 0 677 / Fax +41 44 583 0 678
```

(The number works on 8th April 2016, might not work if they change it again)